# List containers a user has access to in Azure storage

Tags: c#, azure, storage

Given an accesstoken that allows me access to an Azure storage account, (so I can read/write blobs on behalf of a user), I would also like to be able to discover all the containers the user has read/write access to in the storage account.

Is there a way in C#, to get a list of these containers? I know that there is a general way to get a list of all containers (for example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-containers-list?tabs=dotnet), but the user would need read access on the storage account for this, and I just want to find the containers the user has access to.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you are using Azure AD Auth to protect your blob containers, and you want to get a container list that a user has read access.

Basically, if a user with roles: `Storage Blob Data Contributor`, `Storage Blob Data Owner`,`Storage Blob Data Reader` of a container, will have read access. Details [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles).

So we just need to check under a storage account scope, if this user is granted anyone of these 3 roles. We can do it via the Azure Management API, just refer to the console application code below:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace AzureRoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var subscriptionID = "<your subscription ID>";
            var userObJId = "<user Object ID>";
            var storageAccountName = "<storage Account name>";
            var resourceGroup = "<resource group name>";

            var adminAccessToken = "<access token to call Azure management API>";

            List<Role> destRoles = new List<Role>();
            destRoles.Add(new Role() { name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor", RoleId = "ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe" });
            destRoles.Add(new Role() { name = "Storage Blob Data Owner", RoleId = "2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1" });
            destRoles.Add(new Role() { name = "Storage Blob Data Reader", RoleId = "db58b8e5-c6ad-4a2a-8342-4190687cbf4a" });


            //get all role assigment records relatged to a user under a storage account 
            var requestUrl = @"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/"+ subscriptionID + "/resourceGroups/"+resourceGroup+"/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/" + storageAccountName + "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?$filter=principalId eq '" + userObJId + "'&api-version=2020-04-01-preview";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + adminAccessToken);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoleList>(responseFromServer);

                Console.WriteLine("User has permission to access containers:");
                //Filter roles that has permission to read container 
                foreach (var roleItem in result.value){
                    var destRole = destRoles.Find(x => roleItem.properties.roleDefinitionId.Contains(x.RoleId) && roleItem.properties.scope.Contains("containers"));
                    if (destRole != null) {

                        Console.WriteLine("Container Name:" + roleItem.properties.scope.Substring(roleItem.properties.scope.LastIndexOf("/") + 1) + " Role:" + destRole.name );
                    } 
                }
                


            }

            // Close the response.
            response.Close();


        }




        public class Role { 
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string RoleId{ get; set; }
        }

        public class Properties
        {
            public string roleDefinitionId { get; set; }
            public string principalId { get; set; }
            public string principalType { get; set; }
            public string scope { get; set; }
            public object condition { get; set; }
            public object conditionVersion { get; set; }
            public DateTime createdOn { get; set; }
            public DateTime updatedOn { get; set; }
            public string createdBy { get; set; }
            public string updatedBy { get; set; }
            public object delegatedManagedIdentityResourceId { get; set; }
            public object description { get; set; }
        }

        public class RoleDetils
        {
            public Properties properties { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

        public class RoleList
        {
            public List<RoleDetils> value { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you; very useful!!

Comment: Hi  @EdwinStraver, Glad to know it is helpful for you :) Please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark this post as an answer to close this case, thanks !!